# Sales button linked to another site

Tags: web, button, linked-list, hyperlink

I am the author of a book that is sold through the publisher. The thing is that I would like to create a website to promote this book and I wanted to create a sales section where I would like to include a buy button that works as follows:

- A form appears with the method of payment, shipping and then data such as name, address etc. (it includes everything that the publisher's website asks for).
  What I would like is that this information that you fill in on my website is automatically sent to the publisher's website so that they can send them the product (that is, even if you buy on my website, you are buying directly from the publisher).
  I think it is something very simple and straightforward as this is how dropshipping works with shopify and aliexpress, but I can't find any information on the internet.
  If you could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Why not include an `iframe` element on your page that shows the publisher's page where all this data entry and can be done?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.